# how to create resources without VS C++ 2008 creating MFC files

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am creating a WIN32 application and I want most of all my application events to be made through the message queue. But everytime I create a dialog box or any resource like that. The IDE auto generates code that I don't necessarily need. I believe it's MFC code not sure. here it is.

```
// dlgChangeDevice.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ZFXD3D.h"
#include "dlgChangeDevice.h"


// dlgChangeDevice dialog

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(dlgChangeDevice, CDialog)

dlgChangeDevice::dlgChangeDevice(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(dlgChangeDevice::IDD, pParent)
{

}

dlgChangeDevice::~dlgChangeDevice()
{
}

void dlgChangeDevice::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(dlgChangeDevice, CDialog)
    ON_CBN_SELCHANGE(IDC_COMBO5, &dlgChangeDevice::OnCbnSelchangeCombo5)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// dlgChangeDevice message handlers

void dlgChangeDevice::OnCbnSelchangeCombo5()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
}
```

Not sure what it is but I don't need it. I want to retrieve all my code through the dialog message queue. So what should I do ?? Just disregard it and delete it. Will a hurt anything by doing so ??

[edit]

I guess, in a nutshell, is it possible to create a resource without that code being added

Comment: StackOverflow just popped this question back to the front page, and I'm afraid I don't have anything to add - if it's not a MFC project, VS should not be creating this file. I don't believe it will hurt anything if you delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a plain old Win32 project; if you create a MFC project then you are going to get all this wizard-generated stuff.

Comment: The application I started was a WIN32 project. It was a empty one at that. It wasnt until I added resource and selected dialog did all the extra stuff was created. I don't know, maybe it was something I pressed